# What to do with overly generic tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a number of tags so far that seem overly generic, and that don't seem to add a whole lot to the questions they're used on. In particular I'm thinking of [engineering](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering), [experiment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experiment), and [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology). Should we keep these tags or get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

Note poor tags is worse than no tags. Once we're past early beta, new users will not be able to create new tags until they reach given karma. They must make do with what we have, and considering we have some rather broad subjects, it would be hard to invent all possible detailed tags to cover them all - so let's give them generic tags for now, and retag successively.

Answer (score 2):

Work to improve the tagging for those questions that can. If there's a tag that is genuinely new, then we'll leave it be, but if a tag set can be improved, it should be improved.