# Community Policy Repository

Tags: discussion, faq

This is the official repository for general community policy decisions.

### On Posts

- [What is the best approach to asking questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/315/58)
- [Can I write an answer to my own question and accept it?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1432/58)
- [When can I post multiple answers to the same question?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/612/58)
- [Is the use of ChatGPT or other chatbot software forbidden?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3000/58)

---

### On Topics

#### Scope

- [What are the rules for science fiction questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/58)
- [When are physics questions on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/58)
- [Is planetary science on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/313/58)
- [Which celestial mechanics questions are on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1494/58)
- [Can I ask for guidance on making my own rocket engine or fuel?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031/58)
- [When are programming questions on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/996/58) (asked about [python](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) specifically)
- [Can I ask about my idea to solve this problem?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1170/58)
- [What are the rules about homework questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/984/58)
- [Are military questions on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/58)

#### Resources

- [Where can I find resources such as books to get additional information about space exploration?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/58)
- [Where can I find educational materials about space exploration?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/505/58)
- [Where can I find space exploration infographics?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/58)
- [Where can I find software tools for space exploration?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/790/58)
- [How do we know the moon landings are real?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1011/58)

#### Editing Guidance

- [If something changes names, do the tag and old posts need to be updated?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1194/58)

---

### On Tags

#### Requests

- [Where do I request tags to be merged/synonymized?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/62/58)

#### Naming

- [Can tags have the word "space" in them?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/58)
- [Should tags containing multiple words separate the words with hyphens?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/58)

#### Tag Excerpt and Wiki

- [Should tag excerpts begin with the word "Questions"?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291/58)
- [Should I copy a snippet of the Wikipedia entry for a topic into the tag wiki?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/179/58)

#### Maintenance

- [What should I do with overly generic tags?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83/58)
- [When can tags be created for speculative craft/missions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/58)

#### Usage

- [Should I create a new tag?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1478/58)
- [When should I use country tags?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1111/58)

---

### On Writing Guidelines

#### Titles

- [I'm not sure this creative question title is helpful. What should I do about that?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1430/58)

#### Markup

- [Can I fix someone's link markup? I don't like it.](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1355/58)
- [Should I use MathJax markup in my question title?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/987/58)

#### Grammar

- [What pronouns should I use for individuals?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1397/58)
- [Which version of English spelling should be used?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/58)
- [What are the rules for abbreviations?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/309/58)

#### Sources

- [Can I use Wikipedia as a source?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/185/58)
- [Are sci-hub links allowed?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1618/58)
- [I'm referencing an offline source I'd like to make available online. Is there a way I can do that?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1047/58)
- [When should I include a video?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/575/58)
- [Are sources required?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/58)

#### Standards

- [Should I say "astronaut", "cosmonaut", or something else?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/58)
- [Which units of measurement should I use (e.g. feet or meters)?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/288/58)

---

### On Chat

- [Can I create a new chat room?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/732/58)
- [Where can I request feeds be added/removed from the main chat room?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/279/58)

Comment: A super useful resource!

Comment: @uhoh Yes, feel free to add anything that's relevant. I borrowed the idea from History.SE.

Comment: I [wonder where they got that idea from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) ;)

Comment: @Machavity This is a little bit different than that, because this isn't just for any how to question but specifically issues that the community had to make a decision regarding how we would handle. But they may, in fact, have been inspired by the MSE FAQ nevertheless.

Comment: Re-reading it, that might have sounded snarky. Didn't mean it that way

Comment: @Machavity It didn't sound snarky to me. :) But I did want to make sure to make the distinction, because it's not just for any question. For example, this question would not belong on this list because the answer is simply based on SE policy and what tools are available to mods; the community did not have to decide how that situation would be handled: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/917/58

Comment: the link for "Which celestial mechanics questions are on topic?" points to an answer that no longer meets the (lowered-bar) criteria for acceptance. Should it be updated to the answer than meets both the current and original criteria ?

Comment: @JCRM We ran that particular policy decision as a first-past-the-post vote, so it is now established policy. If we want to propose changing it, the fairest way would be to have a new meta discussion. Meta posts that have been sitting around for awhile have votes that may be a mix of active and inactive users, so they are not a good gauge of what the community may currently support. As controversial as this issue has been, I think a new meta discussion would need to take place in two phases: phase 1 would determine how the policy is set (vote threshholds, etc.) ...

Comment: @JCRM ...and phase 2 would determine the policy itself using the criteria established in phase 1. So that would actually be two separate meta questions.

Comment: There was nothing in the question about it being run as first past the post (and that does go against the way stack exchange tends to work) until you unanimously declared it to have been won on that basis. Your comment "they are not a good gauge of what the community may currently support" is an argument *against* community policies.

Comment: @JCRM It was a mod team decision. It wasn't made unilaterally.

Comment: I suggest you refer this to the other moderators, as there could be an appearance that you are biased towards the community opinion you drafted

Comment: @JCRM We already discussed it, and as I've stated many times, the answer I drafted is not my opinion. I don't have a dog in this fight, but I've been watching this discussion go on for some time and have seen the pendulum swing back and forth. I'm just trying to make sure it is done in a fair way that doesn't result in a lot of confusion about what is on topic, and I have conferred with the other mods through this process.

Comment: that's why I referred to it as "the opinion you drafted" not "your opinion" -- I have clarified that further.

Comment: @JCRM Ok, thanks for clarifying. I have said from early on that I would support an answer that clearly delineates that these questions are off-topic. It would save me a lot of grief. What I *don't* want to see is the scope of the site change every year as more people see the policy and the votes swing one way or another. We need to find a way to make something more stable than that so that people don't get confused and we don't have to keep flipping historical locks on and off on old questions.

Comment: @JCRM FYI - I have notified the other mods about this discussion so they can look over it and weigh in.

Comment: Looked at the celestial mechanics answers, and you are right that it doesn't seem to have a clear majority, although the current top answer is slightly in favor of not including such questions. It seems to me that opening a new question would be appropriate, with a clearer defined "Allow some" vs "Allow none" type answers to better allow for voting.